# Android HttpPost response returning code of website

Tags: php, javascript, android, eclipse, http-post

I've made the Android app correctly using Eclipse, there are no errors there.

What my app should do -
Send a string to my server which should return another value which I want to display.

The problem is that the php page im sending the data to also has a lot of Javascript. Mostly javascript rather. And instead of executing the javascript code, it is displaying it.

Example :

Sending String "hello" through App

PHP Page:

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['txt'];
echo $string;
?>
<script type="javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?sfgdata=+sfgRmluamFuX1R5cGU9amF2YV9zY3JpcHQmRmluamFuX0xhbmc9dGV4dC9qYXZhc2NyaXB0+q"></script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" SRC="/CyberSpin/subvar.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" SRC="/CyberSpin/wordsub.js"></SCRIPT>
<script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Output:

hello [followed by all the script lines]

This also happens for all the javascript code i have next!

PS - Im displaying the response text using a Toast. What am i doing wrong? What do I do now?

Comment: Did you try removing javascript code to see what will happen?

Comment: yeah! the simple php works fine! its the javascript that is being displayed as simple text instead of being executed :/

Comment: DO you need to have javascript there?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually expected behavior.
You're making a typical http request and getting all the response body, the javascript won't be processed.
If you wan't it to be evaled consider using webview, otherwise just remove it from response

Comment: i dont need the javascript for the response. The javascript is suppose to work on the text sent and return another text which should be the response.. instead the whole code is being sent back as response :/

And yes, i do need the javascript there..

Comment: If you wan't to load a webpage inside the app you need to use webview, that creates an instance of native web browser which is going to properly evaluate the html and javascript(don't forget to whitelist the domain in manifest).
If you are trying to create a server side api forget about this aproach all the logic is supposed to be proccessed on backend